# A condition of Leray-Hirsch theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology

This is the Leray-Hirsch theorem on Hatcher's Algebraic Topology.

Theorem 4D.1. Let $F \rightarrow E \xrightarrow{p} B$ be a fiber bundle such that, for some commutative coefficient ring $R$ :
(a) $H^n(F ; R)$ is a finitely generated free $R$-module for each $n$.
(b) There exist classes $c_j \in H^{k_j}(E ; R)$ whose restrictions $i^*\left(c_j\right)$ form a basis for $H^*(F ; R)$ in each fiber $F$, where $i: F \rightarrow E$ is the inclusion.

Then the map $\Phi: H^*(B ; R) \otimes_R H^*(F ; R) \rightarrow H^*(E ; R), \sum_{i j} b_i \otimes i^*\left(c_j\right) \mapsto \sum_{i j} p^*\left(b_i\right) \smile c_j$, is an isomorphism of $R$-modules.

My question is why we need $c_j$ generates the cohomology of **every** fiber instead of **one** fiber (for example $E_p$). Since the choice of $i$ can be any $i:E_p\rightarrow E$, and then the proof will not change. If not, what is the inclusion $i:F\rightarrow E$ here?

Comment: my guess is that its a connectivity question for the base and that you are correct in the connected case

Comment: What is $E_p{}$?

Comment: $E_p$ is the fiber at point $p$ i.e., $\pi^{-1}(p)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $b_0, b_1 \in B$ are in the same path component then the inclusions $F_{b_i} = p^{-1}(b_i) \to E$ are homotopic, so induce the same map on cohomology (once $F_{b_0}$ and $F_{b_1}$ have been identified by trivializing $p$ along a path connecting $b_0$ to $b_1$). In particular if $B$ is path connected and the images of $c_j$ generate the cohomology of one fiber then they generate the cohomology of every fiber under the respective restriction.

A reason for phrasing the statement in that way is a combination of allowing $B$ to be not path connected and eliding the choice of $b \in B$ that the fiber is being taken. It would be equally fine to require that every path component of $B$ contains some point $b \in B$ such that the images of $c_j$ by restricting along $F_b \to E$ generate.

Comment: You answered my question perfectly. Thank you.